# How to see the second fundamental form is symmetric when defining it as the derivative of the Gauss map?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

Let $X \subset \mathbb C^N$ be an $n$-dimensional complex submanifold.
Voisin writes in [1]

> Let us introduce the second fundamental form
> $$\Phi: S^2 T_{X,x} \to \mathbb C^N / T_{X,x}$$
> which can be defined as the differential of the Gauss map
> $$\varphi:X \to \operatorname{Grass}(n,N),\ x \mapsto T_{X,x}.$$

Set $G = \operatorname{Grass}(n,N)$, and let $0 \to A \to \underline{\mathbb C}^n \to B \to 0$ be the universal short exact sequence of vector bundles on $G$. The differential of the Gauss map fits into a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T_X @>>> T_G @= \operatorname{Hom}(A,B) \\
@VVV @VVV @.\\
X @>>> G @.
\end{CD}$$
As $A_{\varphi(x)} = T_{X,x}$ and $B_{\varphi(x)} = \mathbb C^N / T_{X,x}$, we get  bilinear maps $$T_{X,x} \times T_{X,x} \to \mathbb C^N / T_{X,x}.$$

But why is this map symmetric?

---

[1] Voisin, *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry II*

Comment: My favorite way to answer this uses a moving frames computation in differential geometry. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\C{\mathbb{C}}$UPSHOT: If $f: X \rightarrow \C^N$ is the inclusion map, $\partial^2f$ is the Hessian with respect to local coordinates, and $\pi_x: \C^N \rightarrow \C^N\backslash T_xX$ is the quotient map, then it is easy to show that,
$$
x \mapsto \pi_x(\partial^2 f(x))
$$
is a section of $S^2T^*X\otimes \C^N/T_*X$. The longwinded discussion below is an attempt to explain why it is the second fundamental form.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

As always, symmetry like this arises from the fact that partials commute.

Here's one way to do it using local coordinates and affine coordinates for the Grassmannian:

Given $p \in X$, move $X$ to a position such $p$ is at the origin, and the tangent plane at $p$ is $T_0 = \{z^{n+1}=\cdots =z^N = 0\}$. In a suitably chosen neighborhood $O \subset \C^N$ of $0$, $X$ is a graph of a map $f: T_0 \rightarrow \C^{N-n}$, i.e.,
$$ X = \{ (z,f(z))\}. $$

The Grassmannian $G(n,N)$ in a neighborhood $N$ of $T_0$ is parameterized by linear maps $L: T_0 \rightarrow \C^N/T_0$. Each linear map maps to its graph. In particular, if $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the space of all linear maps from $T_0$ to $\C^N/T_0$, then there is a natural injective map
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &\rightarrow G(n,N)\\
L &\mapsto \{ v + L(v):\ v \in T_0\}.
\end{align*}

The Gauss map is the map from $z\in$ near $0$ to
$$
\phi(z) = T_zX = \{ v + \partial f(z)(v):\ v \in T_0 \} \in G(n,N).
$$
Equivalently, using the affine coordinate map $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow G(n,N)$, it defines a map
\begin{align*}
X &\rightarrow \mathcal{L}\\
z &\mapsto \partial f(x).
\end{align*}
Since $\partial f(x)$ is a linear map from $T_0$ to $\C^N/T_0$, its derivative at $0$ is a map
$$ \partial^2f(0): T_0\otimes T_0 \rightarrow \C^N/T_0. $$ Since partial commute, it is really a map
$$ \partial^2f(0): S^2T_0 \rightarrow \C^N/T_0. $$
This is the second fundamental form.

There are, of course, details to check, including verifying that this really is the second fundamental form and that it is a tensor (i.e, a bundle map). What is crucial is that the second fundamental form at each point $x \in X$ is obtained by writing $X$ locally as a graph over $T_xX$ of a function $f: T_xX \rightarrow \C^N/T_xX$. Then $0 \in T_xX$ is a crticial point of $f$, and, as a consequence, the Hessian of $f$ at $0$ is a well-defined tensor.

Comment: I think this mostly works, and I way able to convince myself that you get indeed the Hessian, which is symmetric. Thanks! One subtlety though: The embedding $\mathcal L \to G(n,N)$ depends on the choice of a splitting $\mathbb C^N / T_0 \to \mathbb C^N$. Two different splittings can easily produce different subspaces of $\mathbb C^N$, for the same map $\varphi \in \mathcal L$. I will write some details I checked in a second answer, feel free to copy them if you like.

Comment: I believe that the embedding does not in fact depend on the splitting. The standard way to define affine coordinates uses a splitting but if you use the quotient space instead of a transversal subspace, then you eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: The ambiguity goes away if you want to identify the tangent space to the Grassmannian (cf. Voisin, Hodge Theory I, **Lemma 10.7**), but it is not true for the open embedding. Consider the case of $\mathbb P^1 = G(1,2)$, with base point $x = [1,0]$. Then $\mathcal L = \mathbb C$. The splitting corresponds to a point $y \in \mathbb P^1 \setminus \{x\}$, and the embedding is given by $\mathcal L = \mathbb C \ni \lambda \mapsto x + \lambda y$. So the point which is missed by this chart is $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Those are my computational details to Deane's answer:

We have wlog $x = 0 \in X$, and $V = T_{X,x} = \langle e_1, \dotsc, e_n \rangle_{\mathbb C} \subset \mathbb C^N$. Let $D \subset \mathbb C^n$ be a small disc, and let $f: D \to \mathbb C^N$ be a local parametrisation of $X$, with $f(0) = 0$. For $z \in D$, the tangent space $T_{X,f(z)}$ is generated by the columns of the differential matrix
$$Df = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_1}(z) & \dots & 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_n}(z) \\
\vdots && \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_N}{\partial z_1}(z) & \dots & 
\frac{\partial f_N}{\partial z_n}(z)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
As Deane explained, we have an open inclusion $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \hookrightarrow G(n,N)$, which maps a map $\varphi: V \to W$ to the subspace
$(\operatorname{id} + \varphi)(V).$ Now with respect to the two open charts chosen, the Gauß map $X \to G(n,N), x \mapsto T_{X,x}$ is given by cutting the upper rows of $Df$ ("projecting to $W$"), i.e.
$$D \ni z \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{n+1}}{\partial z_1}(z) & \dots & 
\frac{\partial f_{n+1}}{\partial z_n}(z) \\
\vdots && \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_N}{\partial z_1}(z) & \dots & 
\frac{\partial f_N}{\partial z_n}(z)
\end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W).$$
Differentiating this yields the Hessian matrices for the $f_i, i > n$.